# Confused on nested routes controller settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble with a homework assignment. I am taking a rails course through Coursera and the directions are ambiguous, to me at least. Also, asking questions in the class forum is hit or miss since the forums are pretty dead and usually don't replies for days. So this assignment has us nesting resources. What I'm having trouble understanding is step 6 of the requirements.

```
a. Remove the old URI comments or replace them to have the following form since all calls to a TodoItem will
now be scoped below a TodoList. Use the todo_item output of rake routes to give you a head start.
$ rake routes
#METHOD /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items
#METHOD /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id

b. Remove the todo_item#index method and views/todo_items/index pages. This will no longer be called
since all TodoItem displays will be scoped to a particular TodoList. We will get the TodoList and call
todo_list.todo_items() instead.

c. Add a private helper method called set_todo_list that sets the @todo_list instance variable from the
:todo_list_id property passed in via the params.

d. Update the private helper method called set_todo_item to scope its find command to the todo_items of
a specific @todo_list list.

e. Invoke the set_todo_list method before each method in the controller is executed using a before_action

f. Update the todo_item#new action to return a new TodoItem instance that is initialized to reference its
parent @todo_list, which is provided by set_todo_list.

g. Update the todo_item#create to create a new TodoItem instance based on the todo_item_params as
before. Except now create this instance associated with the @todo_list provided by set_todo_list.

h. Update the HTML redirect of the todo_item#create, todo_item#update, and todo_item#destroy methods
to do to the todo_list#index page.
```

So I'm mostly concerned/confused on steps D, F, G, and H. I think all this occurs in the todo_items controller. Here is my file. The more I search, the more I get confused. Any help is appreciated.

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list
  before_action :set_todo_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1
  # GET /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/new
  def new
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new
  end

  # GET /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items
  # POST /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items.json
  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_item.update(todo_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1
  # DELETE /todo_list/:todo_list_id/todo_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todo_lists_url, notice: 'Todo item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    end

    def set_todo_item
      @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_item_params
      params.require(:todo_item).permit(:title, :due_date, :description, :completed)
    end
end
```

Comment: First: You're confusing us, too. Because we don't know for example if this todo items controller is what you had to start with, or what you already changed, and if so we don't know which of your tasks were done already. It would be easier if you'd take a step back and think of what is the difference. First you had todo lists, then you had todo items. Now you nested them. So the way their data ist provided changed, but Rails does not automatically change the controller accordingly - here is where you come in.

Comment: Start from the end, I'd say. Because task h) easily supports my view. The create method of the todo_item would normally redirect to a place where the todo items *were* before you nested them. So *now* they are at a different place, and that's what you have to do in h) at least. And the other tasks are similar in their purpose.

Comment: This todo_items controller reflects what I changed. I think I did task H properly. It used to say `redirect_to @todo_item` and now it says `redirect_to @todo_list`. I did all the tasks already but I'm not sure if they're done right. In the next step, step 7, it tells me exactly what to do but the rspec fails.

Comment: It does not. ;) `@todo_item` only worked by convention. If the "normal" behavior/route changes you have to be a bit more precise. Right now the user would be redirected to the `@todo_list` if he created or updated the item... but he should be redirected to the todo item nested at the todo list. The easiest way for you to follow your tasks is trial and error. Do you have a webserver running? Open the browser, add an item push the button and see if it does what it should. If not, change it. This way you learn a lot. And `rake routes` helps you with you redirection paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
#app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
   before_create :set_todo_list

   def new
      @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new
   end

   private

   def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find params[:todo_list_id]
   end
end
```

I typed this before looking at your code; it's basically what the question was asking.

---

The questions themselves seem to be about *scoping* your methods around the `TodoList` object. Once you understand how it works, it should be pretty simple...

--

Rails uses [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) as its *[ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)* (Object Relationship Mapper).

In simple terms, this means that you can build SQL queries with Ruby "objects", letting ActiveRecord create the query as you need.

This is *very* important because you have to realize that Ruby/Rails is an [*object orientated*](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/object-oriented-programming) framework & language. Object orientated programming is basically where you treat data as *objects* (not variables), load them into memory, and manipulate them as the user interacts with the app.

[Games are huge proponents of object orientated programming](http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/09/object-oriented-programming-in-a-nutshell/):

[image]

With Rails apps, each time you create / invoke a "variable", you're really manipulating an *object*, and as such, you can use ActiveRecord in conjunction with this to create objects as you desire.

--

This is important for several reasons; but mostly because it means you can "scope" requests around objects.

In your case, you want to create a new `TodoItem` for each `TodoList` in your application.

The simple way to set this up is as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :todo_lists do
   resources :todo_items #-> url.com/todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id
end

#app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @todo_list = TodoList.find params[:todo_list_id]
      @todo_item = @todo_list.items.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

I can update the answer with specifics regarding your requests if you want. If you understand the above, it should pretty simple though.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I believe the lines under the show method is what fixed it for me. I'm very new to rails so it's all confusing to me.

Comment: If you tell me what you're confused about, I'll do my best to answer if you want

Comment: Why thank you! 2 things right now. Why do the parameters differ in the show method? In one there is :todo_list_id and the other, it's just :id. How do you know when to use which? Secondly, the output of rake routes is kind of big. How do I know which verb to use for my redirect_to lines?